# How to avoid rerunning actions in Rx pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have an Rx pipeline where some entities are created base on incoming data, then these entities should be persisted and when they have completed a status should be printed.

I have tried the following code. The problem is that it reruns the action many times, instead of just a single time, so I get multiple copies of the entities in the database. Basically with the code below I would like to to print "persisting test1" only a single time.

```
        var test1Observable = Observable.Return("test1");
        var test2Observable = Observable.Return("test2");

        var createTest1Observable = test1Observable.Select(name => name);
        var test1 = createTest1Observable.Do(x => Console.WriteLine("persisting test1"));

        var createTest3Observable = Observable.CombineLatest<string, string, Tuple<string,string>>(test1, test2Observable, (t1, t2) => new Tuple<string,string>(t1,t2));
        var persistTest3Observable = createTest3Observable.Do(x => Console.WriteLine("persisting test 3"));

        var createTest4Observable = test1.Select(x => "test4");
        var persistTest4Observable = createTest4Observable.Do(x => Console.WriteLine("persisting test 4"));

        var createTest5Observable = test1.Select(x => "test5");
        var persistTest5Observable = createTest5Observable.Do(x => Console.WriteLine("persisting test5"));

        var OnSuccesObservable = Observable.CombineLatest<string, Tuple<string,string>, string, string, bool>(test1, persistTest3Observable, persistTest4Observable, persistTest5Observable, (t1, t2, t3, t4) =>
        {
            if (t1 == null || t2 == null || t3 == null || t4 == null)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        });

        OnSuccesObservable.Subscribe(
           o =>
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Finished");
               Console.ReadLine();
           });
```

Comment: `var persistTest2Entity = createTest1Entity.Do(persistor);` -- Should that be createTest*2*Entity.Do(...)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited and fixed the typo in the question now. It doesn't fix the problem though.

Comment: I realize my initial code example was a bit too simplified and didn't show the problem that well so I edited it so it shows better. The code prints "persisting test1" many times, but I'd like it to happen only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making test1 a connectable observable

```
var test1 = createTest1Observable.Do(x => Console.WriteLine("persisting test1")).Publish();
```

then after all the other code connect to it as follows

```
var connected = test1.Connect();
```

This ensures the observable is shared correctly and not resubscribed to

Comment: A great explanation here http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html

Comment: This does indeed seem to fix the problem. Thanks. I'll have to look more into how connectable observables work.